Keep value for onchange radio buttons in .map
I am using a .map to show a list of people:
const [ftraveller, setFTraveller] = useState(null)

{tr?.map((item, i) => {
return (  
<>
<FormControlLabel key={el.id + item.Name}  control={<Radio onChange={(e) => setFTraveller(e.target.value)} />} value={item.Name} name={el.id + item.Name} label={item.Name}></FormControlLabel>
</>
)})}
</RadioGroup>

And then using ftraveller to show a list of options available for that person:
{getselecteddata.map(els => {
return (
<>
<RadioGroup key={els.id} value={els.packingLocation ? els.packingLocation : "To Pack"} defaultValue="To Pack" row
onChange={e => {
const val = e.target.value
const getd = getselecteddata.map(els => {
return {
...els,
packingLocation: val,
}
})
const ar = [...getalldata, ...getd]
setFoodValue(ar)
}}>

<FormControlLabel value={"A - " + ftraveller} control={
<Radio
value={"A - " + ftraveller}
name={el.id + "A - " + ftraveller}
/>
}
label={"A"}
/>

<FormControlLabel value={"B - " + ftraveller} control={
<Radio
value={"B - " + ftraveller}
name={el.id + "B - " + ftraveller}
/>
}
label={"B"}
/>
</RadioGroup>
</>
)})}

The issue I have is that if I change the person then the option checked then changes for everyone else. So it looks like everytime I change the radio setFTraveller is set to the most recent selection.
How do I change this to uniquely store setFTraveller for each item?

There is multiple way to do so, the most plain is to use ftravellers as array:
// create new array and fill it with false
// new Array(tr?.lenght).fill(false)

const [ftravellers, setFTravellers] = useState(new Array(tr?.lenght).fill(false));

then in your radio:
<Radio onChange={(e) => setFTravellers(fts => {
   let arr = [...fts];
   arr[i] = e.target.value;
   return arr;
})} value={ftravellers[i]} />

as you can see it's ok but kinda clumsy
Other approach (what i would normally do in a case where i want to keep all array at parent component:
// define array as empty array, and push/remove item id
const [ftravellers, setFTravellers] = useState([])

const handleRadio = (ftravellerId) => {
  if (ftravellers.include(id))
     setFTravellers(ftravellers.filter(({id}) => id !== ftravellerId);
  else 
     setFTravellers([...ftravellers, id]);
}

// then in the radio:
<Radio onChange={(e) => handleRadio(id)} value={travelers?.include(id)} ... />

as you can see much more cleaner approach
Third option is to create a component from your radio, and keep state in there, but i think it not going to suit, if you want to u this state elsewhere.
